# How to match a world with a list of items

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that imports data, and I need to have a Colum that returns a different word based on what would be in Colum H. So if the sheets loads in, and it has "Green" in Colum H I want Colum AH to return a skill or queue.

**EXAMPLE:**

Colum H = Green then Colum AH = Queue1, Colum H = Red then Colum AH = Queue2 (I have about 20 queues)  - This would just populate the queue name when the information loads in.

- What this does is display "Queue1" whenever H has the word green in it if it's blank it just displaces "not found" I need to do this, but with a list of items. green  = queue1, blue = queue 2, red = queue 3 etc all in one formula.

  =IF(COUNTIF(H1565,"Green"),"Queue1", "Not Found")

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: So I just want to return a value if an exact match word is populated. H = Green then I want AH to automatically display the "queue" for green as H populates into the sheet. 

So "H" will give me about 20 different names and I need to map these names to a queue. (each queue will be different for each name)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A10; D:E; 2; ); "Not Found"))
```

[image]